# EF IQueryable Extension Methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've started building extension methods for my EF classes like below because it makes building queries so easy, and the intellisense provided helps keep people from writing a new Where() clause in code every time they do to do something.

**Example Extensions to an EF User Class**

```
public static class UserIQX
{
    public static IQueryable<User> WhereInSearch(this IQueryable<User> value, string search)
    {
        search = search.ToLower();
        return value.Where(user => user.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(search) || user.LastName.ToLower().Contains(search) || user.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(search));
    }


    public static IQueryable<User> WhereInRole(this IQueryable<User> value, RoleEnum role)
    {
        return value.Where(user => user.RoleID == (int)role);
    }
}
```

**Examples - "Get all admins named Bob"**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var search = "Bob";

    //With Extensions
    var activeAdmins = db.Users
    .WhereInRole(RoleEnum.Admin)
    .WhereInSearch(search)
    .Select(u => new { EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress })
    .ToList();

    //Without extensions
    search = search.ToLower();
    var pq = db.Users
        .Where(u => (
            u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(search) 
            || u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(search) 
            || u.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(search)) 

            && u.RoleID == (int)RoleEnum.Admin)
        .Select(u => new { EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress })
        .ToList();
}
```

**Results**
[image]

The results are comparable with the inline one edging out ahead in speed. It's interesting that the extension-based one used a parameter for the roleID and the inline one did not.  That's the only real difference I can see.

I *really* like the fluent-like style the Extension method provides, and how it encapsulates logic to prevent erroneous queries from being written (like forgetting to `ToLower()` the string fields or something).  Is there a good reason why this would be a *Really Bad Idea*?  If not, I prefer the easy maintainability of the Extension methods over inline.

Comment: Fully agree. I'm using this full out through my projects, in combination with overloading. You'll get like `Db.Comments.By(currentUser).By(thread).OrderByDate()`. Personally I think it is really readable and well maintainable, but I still need to test that with others ;)

Comment: So in your example I would take it even a step further: `db.Users.By(RoleEnum.Admin).FilterBy(keyword).SelectEmails()` - but quite curious what others think.

Comment: Normally I extract the expressions themselves into reusable methods, but I really like this idea.

Answer (score 3):

By moving this question from StackOverflow to here, [usr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr)'s sensible remarks were lost. I restore them here as community wiki:

No, this is fine and recommended. You'll find a limitation of this approach: You cannot use these extension methods in places where they get turned into an expression:

```
db.Something.Any(x => x.Users.WhereInRole(RoleEnum.Admin))
```

This does not work because EF does not know the `WhereInRole` method.

The `AsExpandable` extension method can help with this. Search the web to find it as a small library.

Using the same approach you should be able to inline constants such as the role ID into the query as well.

---

Note, that the design of `WhereInRole` is not really ideal. Normally, you'd write a method `bool IsUserInRole(User, int)`. No need to operate on sequences at all. The only reason this is not possible here is that you need to find a way to marshal the filtering logic into the final expression tree. Shoving the logic into the argument to `Where` is a hack to do that. This issue/concern is a "dirty secret" of LINQ. It's quite hacky and arbitrary.